# Override default behavior of TAB in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing

I am implementing a JTextPane-based text editor.
Currently, when I have a piece of selected text, pressing the TAB key deletes the selected text. I would like to change this behavior such that TAB will indent the selected text.

How to go about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something along the line of:

```
public void keyPressed ( KeyEvent event ) {
        switch ( event.getKeyCode ()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_TAB :
                insertTabChar ( event.isShiftDown ());
                event.consume ();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_ENTER :
                snapshot ();
                insertNewLine ();
                event.consume ();
                break;
        }
    }
```

You have some classes out there which do just that, like [this one](http://www.koders.com/java/fid111B2AEDC5B123210487BE5E4260AD37FE5E6ACF.aspx?s=JTextPane+indent+tab#L70).

In particular, the function

```
    /**
     * manage keyboard tabbing, implementing blockindent.
     * @param isUnindent
     */
    private void insertTabChar ( boolean isUnindent ) {

        snapshot (); // snapshot current setup

        if ( isSelection ) { // blockindent
```

might do just what you need.

Answer (score 2):

The other way is to redefine action for JTextArea component associated with TAB key. Take look at ActionMap.